# Validation rule not working with Rollup Summary field

Tags: validation-rule, roll-up-summary

I have a rollup summary field which just calculates sum of weights from child records and I am trying to apply a validation rule that if IsActive = true && Sum_of_Weights  != 100 then throw an error. Because child weights can be entered more or less than 100 when parent is inactive but once it’s active, weight sum must be 100.

It gives me an error even on positive condition when parent is active and sum is 100 and it’s not letting me edit parent record.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your current rule. Might be useful to see if you want help with it

Answer (score 1):

This objective does not make sense to me unless the intent is to prevent marking the parent object as Active until `Sum_of_Weights__c` equals 100. If this is the case, you can include an `ISCHANGED()` function in your formula:

```
ISCHANGED(IsActive__c) && IsActive__c && Sum_of_Weights__c != 100
```

Then your validation will only go off if a parent object is moved from `IsActive__c = false` to `IsActive__c = true` without `Sum_of_Weights__c` being 100.

You may also need a validation rule on the *child* object to prevent children from being added or removed from an Active parent.

Comment: Thanks David. Yeah want to prevent making parent as active until sum is 100 and adding ISCHANGED didn't work. Its not letting me even to create inactive parent record.

Comment: Sorry ISCHANGED worked on inserting an inactive parent but now its giving me an error when I set from IsActive__c = false to IsActive__c = true and sum is 100

Comment: Paste your actual valuation rule in the question, please.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Parent-Child object are connected via Master Detail relationship. With your validation rule, you will never be able to insert/create Parent (who is active, but having no child). Are you expecting all of your parents will have childrens and also their sum of weights will be exactly 100? Requirement seems a little strange to me. Suggesting you to please recheck the requirements.

But I would like to share this information here for your reference. **The Validation Rule will run on a Parent record 'save' before the record is saved, so before the Total Weight Rollup is re-calculated.**

Comment: Thank Sudipta. Yeah they are linked through master-detail relationship. Also its fine to create an inactive parent record and don't expect parents to have existing children records. I added ISCHANGED but now I am unable to set parent from IsActive__c = false to IsActive__c = true when sum is 100.